# Dataframe Pandas Python top row above all columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a common column for all other columns for a dataframe using pandas in python.

I currently have:

```
                 Flow    %   Z-score
Name1             262  0.2%   0.1
Name2             924  1.6%   1.0
```

And trying to do:

```
                  Combined
             Flow   %   Z-score
Name1         262  0.2%   0.1
Name2         924  1.6%   1.0
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need `MultiIndex`:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Combined'], df.columns])
```

Or:

```
df.columns = [['Combined'] * len(df.columns), df.columns]
```

---

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Combined'], df.columns])
print (df)
      Combined              
          Flow     % Z-score
Name1      262  0.2%     0.1
Name2      924  1.6%     1.0
```

Comment: @user2285236 - Thank you.

Comment: For a reason it ads a gap row between the column names and the data?

Comment: @User5001 - Maybe need `df.index.name = None`

Comment: @User5001 - Is possible share first 2 rows by `df.head(2).to_pickle('file.pkl')` ?

Comment: @User5001 - By google docs or send it to my email in my profile